# while loop stops when condition is still true

Tags: c, while-loop, embedded, volatile, boolean-logic

I have the following code:

```
void EXTI_Main(uint8_t mult)//range 1-4(inclusive)
{
    uint16_t minimum = 200 * mult;
    while(TMR3_GetTick() < minimum);
    printf("mult:%hhu\ttick:%hu\tminimum:%hu\r\n", mult, TMR3_GetTick(), minimum);
    //RF_Main();
    LCD_Read();
    
}
```

with the following output: (don't know how to make blockquote work with line breaks)

```
mult:0  tick:0  minimum:0
mult:1  tick:414        minimum:200
mult:2  tick:453        minimum:400
mult:3  tick:600        minimum:600
mult:4  tick:800        minimum:800
mult:0  tick:0  minimum:0
mult:1  tick:414        minimum:200
mult:2  tick:453        minimum:400
mult:3  tick:600        minimum:600
mult:4  tick:768        minimum:800
mult:0  tick:0  minimum:0
mult:1  tick:414        minimum:200
mult:2  tick:453        minimum:400
mult:3  tick:512        minimum:600
mult:4  tick:768        minimum:800
mult:0  tick:0  minimum:0
```

relevant code in tmr3.c:

```
static volatile uint16_t msTick;//incremented using ISR
uint16_t TMR3_GetTick(void)
{
    return msTick;
}
```

Why is this causing problems when mult == 3 | 4?
is volatile the problem?? I've been reading on how to work with volatile vars and haven't been able to work out if this is part of the problem.

Please ask if more info is required.
Thanks.

EDIT: idk if it's helpful but when they fail, 3 and 4 are always 512(256 * 2) and 768(256*3)

EDIT2: the solution turned out to be:

```
uint16_t tock; while((tock = TMR3_GetTick()) < minimum);
```

Comment: Save the result of `TMR3_GetTick()` in a local variable: it might have moved on by the time you call it again to report its value. `uint16_t tock; while((tock = TMR3_GetTick()) < minimum);` and then report `tock` instead of another call.

Comment: @WeatherVane Hi, I'm like 95% sure I tried that already and it didn't work. But for some reason after copypasting your code it resolved the issue.

Comment: Not sure what CPU you are using, but you should make sure that reading 16-bit values is an atomic operation (i.e. the 16-bits of memory used for `msTick` need to be read by `TMR3_GetTick()` using a single instruction).  Otherwise, if `EXTI_Main()` activates when `TMR3_GetTick()` has only read half of the 16-bits, you may be combining an updated and incremented upper byte with an older lower byte or vis versa.  You can avoid this, if need be, by momentarily disabling the ISR while reading `msTick`.

Comment: Looks like your "ticks" are moving way too fast for what you are trying to do.

Comment: *Hi, I'm like 95% sure I tried that already and it didn't work.* - then show what have you tried. Currently, the behavior of this code is not deterministic.

Comment: The fact that the "wrong" values of 512 and 768 both have the lower 8 bits set to 0 is an indication that @JonathonS. is probably right about the two bytes being updated separately. In that case, putting the result in a local variable only hides the problem rather than solves it.

Comment: You should still save it as a local variable if you want to know the exact value that caused the `while` to end.

Comment: @JonathonS. what exactly do you mean by "a single instruction"? I am returning the variable, is there any other way to do this? 
EDIT: I cannot disable the interrupts since the while is counting every 200th ms, if I disable interrupts, it wont ever reach 200

Comment: @EugeneSh. my ticks increment every ms, I can assure you they are moving at the correct speed. I tried a LOT of things and am not a fan of making my question less readable just so you can see 20 failed attempts, im also not going to find out what I did hours ago. but thanks for complaining.

Comment: @WesleyKienhuis - Whenever the line `return msTick;` is compiled, the code is broken down into one or more instructions that are run by the CPU.  If, say, the CPU has an 8-bit data bus, two separate machine instructions would be needed to copy the contents of RAM where `msTick` is stored.  If the ISR was to interrupt between these two instructions, you would end up reading the first byte before the update and the first byte after.  If the LSB were to overflow during the ISR, the upper and lower bytes would be mismatched.

Comment: @JonathonS. Ahh, that would be the problem, we are using a pic18, which is an 8 bit microcontroller. Thank you for instructing me.

Comment: @Wesley - Glad to help.  The quickest solution will be to disable the interrupt before and after reading `msTicks` and there are other good solutions as well.  On your system, if you want to communicate from the ISR to the other loop, you probably need to make sure you are only communicating 8 bits at a time.  Otherwise, disable interrupts.

Comment: In assembler I would get round that by reading the high byte and then the low byte and then compare the high byte. If is hasn't changed you're good, if it has, then read the low byte again. On the assumtion that the ms part won't wrap twice in that time span.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

shoutout to my man Weather Vane in the comments for this one.

replaced:

```
 while(TMR3_GetTick() < minimum);
```

with:

```
uint16_t tock; while((tock = TMR3_GetTick()) < minimum);
```